# VBA Print to pdf pagesetup.zoom error

Tags: excel, vba

If I step through the following code (F8) it works, apart from this odd message when it gets to the `.Zoom = False`

```
'Print PDF
            Sheets("GRAPHIQUE").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Application.PrintCommunication = True
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$Q$31"
            Application.PrintCommunication = False
            With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
                .LeftHeader = "Fichier: &F"
                .CenterHeader = ""
                .RightHeader = NomClasseurPrincipal 
                .LeftFooter = "Imprimé le: &D à &T"
                .CenterFooter = ""
                .RightFooter = "page &P de &N"
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.708661417322835)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.708661417322835)
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
                .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
                .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
                .PrintHeadings = False
                .PrintGridlines = False
                .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
                .PrintQuality = 600
                .CenterHorizontally = False
                .CenterVertically = False
                .Orientation = xlLandscape
                .Draft = False
        '        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
                .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
                .Order = xlDownThenOver
                .BlackAndWhite = False
                .Zoom = False
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = False
                .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
                .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
                .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
                .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
                .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
                .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
            End With
            Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Say OK to this message

```
"The number must be between 10 and 400. Try again by entering a number in this range."
```

it carries on and working as i wanted but manually with (F8) .

BUT, if I just try to run it (F5) All I get is an error on the
`Application.PrintCommunication = True` line

I suspect an issue in `.zoom=false` because in the msgbox i get `.zoom=100`....

Comment: Generally, if your code runs with F8 but not F5, it's because the code refers to whatever worksheet is active at the time of execution -- as opposed to refering explicitly to a worksheet via workbook and worksheet name. You do not show the beginning of your `With` statement, but maybe check that it's something like: `With Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").pagesetup`. Also, have you tried changing `.Zoom = False` to `.Zoom = 100` or any numeric value?

Comment: i just added the with part. like you said i already tried to put a numeric value between 10 and 400 (tried 10, 400, 60,....) to `.zoom=false` but that's not working the msgbox at the end return all the time `.zoom=100`
i will try to explicit like you suggested the worksheet  `Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").pagesetup`